# Building tags plugin for django-wiki using django-taggit. Cannot save with .save_m2m() - type object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, django-wiki

I am building a custom tags plugin for django-wiki using django-taggit to save tags. I cannot save the form with .save_m2m as it says in the django-taggit docs. The tags can be saved in the admin but not through the fronted form because I cant save with .save_m2m(). I get the following error even after the form has been saved. Any help would be appreciated.

```
type object 'SidebarForm' has no attribute 'save_m2m'
```

wiki_plugins.py

```
class TagPlugin(BasePlugin):

slug = settings.SLUG
sidebar = {
    'headline': _('Tags'),
    'icon_class': 'fa-picture-o',
    'template': 'sidebar.html',
    'form_class': forms.SidebarForm,
    'get_form_kwargs': (lambda a: {'instance': models.Tag(article=a)})
}
```

models.py

```
class TagRevision(RevisionPluginRevision):
def can_write(self, user):
    if not settings.ANONYMOUS and (not user or user.is_anonymous()):
        return False
    return RevisionPlugin.can_write(self, user)

def can_delete(self, user):
    return self.can_write(user)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('tag')
    verbose_name_plural = _('tags')
    db_table = 'wiki__plugins_tags_tag'  # Matches label of upcoming 0.1 release
    if settings.APP_LABEL:
        app_label = settings.APP_LABEL

def __str__(self):
    if self.current_revision:
        return ugettext('Tag: %s') % self.current_revision.tagrevision
    else:
        return ugettext('Current revision not set!!')

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TagRevision(RevisionPluginRevision):

tags = TaggableManager()


def inherit_predecessor(self, tag):
    """
    Inherit certain properties from predecessor because it's very
    convenient. Remember to always call this method before
    setting properties :)"""
    predecessor = tag.current_revision.tagrevision
    self.plugin = predecessor.plugin
    self.deleted = predecessor.deleted
    self.locked = predecessor.locked
    self.tag = predecessor.tag
    if not skip_image_file:
        try:
            self.tags = predecessor.tags

        except IOError:
            self.tags = None

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('tag revision')
    verbose_name_plural = _('tag revisions')
    # Matches label of upcoming 0.1 release
    db_table = 'wiki_plugins_tags_tagrevision'
    if settings.APP_LABEL:
        app_label = settings.APP_LABEL
    ordering = ('-created',)

def __str__(self):
    return ugettext('Tag Revsion: %d') % self.revision_number
```

forms.py

```
from wiki_plugins_tags import models

class SidebarForm(PluginSidebarFormMixin):
    def __init__(self, article, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.article = article
        self.request = request
        super(SidebarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'].required = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.instance.id:
            tagged = models.Tag()
            tagged.article = self.article
            kwargs['commit'] = False
            revision = super(SidebarForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            revision.set_from_request(self.request)
            tagged.add_revision(self.instance, save=True)

            return revision

        return super(SidebarForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = models.TagRevision
        fields = ('tags',)


class RevisionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tags = kwargs.pop('tags')
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(RevisionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'].required = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.instance.id:
            kwargs['commit'] = False
            revision = super(RevisionForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            revision.inherit_predecessor(self.tags, skip_image_file=True)
            revision.deleted = False  # Restore automatically if deleted
            revision.set_from_request(self.request)
            self.tags.add_revision(self.instance, save=True)
            return revision
        return super(RevisionForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = models.TagRevision
        fields = ('tags',)
```